# Javascript code not working after several attempts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to test some JS on a page i'm making. I'm new to it so i'm trying something simple. Apparently it's too challenging for me. Here is my code for the div:

```
<div class="ni">
    <div class="ni_image" onclick="changeColor()">
        <div class="text_box">
            <h3>Northern Ireland</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ni_info">
        <p>info</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the outer div if you need it:

```
.ni {
    width: 600px;
    height: 220px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 60px 0px;
}
```

And the style I'm trying to change in .ni_image:

```
background-color: lightblue;
```

The only other style attributes for this div are width/height, display, and margins/padding. If they're helpful please comment and I'll add them.

Finally here is the JS I'm testing:

```
function changeColor() {
document.getElementsByClassName('.ni_image').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

I've looked at StackOverflow and loads of other forums, and from what I've read I have no idea where I'm going wrong. I've linked the local .js file with a script tag in the head tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to include the `.` in your `getElementsByClassName('.ni_image')`. Try `getElementsByClassName('ni_image')`

Answer (score 1):

When providing arguments to `getElementsByClassName` you don't have to include dot

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ni_image')
```

And remember it returns an HTMLCollection.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does not return an array, it returns an `HTMLCollection`. If it returned an array, you could immediately use Array methods on it such as `map`. However, it must be converted to an array before that can happen. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('ni_image')` returns an Arraylike HTMLCollection, so you must use it as an array
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ni_image')[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Also as already stated, you can not use css selectors with this function, so no dot needed.

You can check the documentation of this function
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp
and it says that the return value is of type `NodeList`, so technically it is not an `Array` but for the most use cases it can be handled as one.

A quick tip I can give: if the function is something like "getElementXXX" like in `getElementById` it will return a single Object and when it says "getElementsXXX" like in `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByName` it will return a `NodeList`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works now. One thing though - what makes it an array? I thought that an array was a var with multiple values? Or is it because there is another div inside it?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does not return an array, it returns an `HTMLCollection`. If it returned an array, you could immediately use Array methods on it such as `map`. However, it must be converted to an array before that can happen. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: @KevBot thanks for your tip. Normally it is enough to know that it returns an array. As for the question why it returns multiple Nodes instead of one: it is because there can be multiple Elements with the same css class and this function returns all of them.

Comment: It is not enough to think that it returns an Array, because, it does not. It is "Array-Like", in the sense that it has indexes, etc. What happens when people start thinking they can do this: `document.getElementsByClassName('foo').forEach(...)`. You get an error that "`forEach is not a function`". That is because it is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have multiple `div`s that have the `ni_image` class you would need to loop through the `HTMLCollection` that is returned by `getElementsByClassName()` if you notice it says `Elements` in the function - as in plural. That is because a class name can be applied to any number of elements, so it is always returning an `HTMLCollection` with all of those elements.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ni_image');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

You can access the elements of the `HTMLCollection` by either using the `[index]` notation or `.items(index)`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list. Setting the `style` field of a list will do nothing.

You need to loop over the list it returns:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ni_image');
elements.forEach(function(e) {
     e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

Comment: you forgot to close the forEach function: `});` at the end instead of `}`

Comment: @DimitriL. Oops. Tried to answer this on my phone while paying for breakfast :/. Thanks.

Comment: @youre welcome. Could not edit it for you, because you need to edit at least 6 characters -_-

Comment: @DimitriL. Ya, always a pain. They need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName))
Try:
 `document.getElementsByClassName('ni_image')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

Answer (score -2):

Don't prepend your class name with ".":

document.getElementsByClassName('ni_image').style.backgroundColor = "red";

Comment: This only fixes one issue. This code still won't work.